# add table of contents in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I don't know why my table of contents doesn't appear in my table of contents!. I am writing:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a5paper,vmargin={5mm,2mm},hmargin={5mm,5mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{backref, colorlinks=true}
\title{ Questions }
\author{Alejandro}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
```

What I am doing wrong?, or how could the numbering starts in chapter 1. Because now, my chapter 1 seems in page 2 in toc but actually it is the page 6.

[image: This is how it looks]

But my chapter 1 is on page 6 not page 2

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: No real minimal example after some delay. Without more information, this question therefore cannot be answered fully. I'm closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page numbering is messed up with respect to the actual location of the table of contents, I've found that it sometimes helps to issue the command `\clearpage` -- or `\cleardoublepage`, if you're using a two-sided layout -- right before issuing the command `\tableofcontents`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a5paper,vmargin={5mm,2mm},hmargin={5mm,5mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{backref, colorlinks=true}
\title{Questions}
\author{Alejandro}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{alph}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{First}
...
```

The first two `\pagenumbering` commands are to keep **hyperref** happy.

Comment: Thanks @egreg just to be clear, when you wrote `\pagenumbering{Alph}` I should write Alph?, because I did it and it seems not to work :(

Comment: Works for me; what's the problem?

Comment: well, it doesn't change anything. pdf looks as before. :(

Comment: @Alejandro: `pagenumering` sets the counter `page` to 0.

Comment: @Alejandro What do you mean? With my code, Chapter 1 starts at page 1 and the ToC reflects it. I don't understand what you mean by "my chapter 1 is on page 6". Please, add something to your code so we can get a feeling about what's going wrong.