# Can you reference the first entry inside the Table of Contents as the Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

This question is similar to [his question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27687/add-table-of-contents-in-table-of-contents).

I made a Table of Contents which doesn't reference the Table of Contents as the first entry.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=6mm, bottom=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
.
.
.

\title{COMPUTATIONAL METHODS FOR THE RIEMANN ZETA FUNCTION}
\author{Axion004}
.
.
.
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble} %????
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{axionstyle}
\pagenumbering{arabic}%
\section*{Summary}
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

The PDF looks like

[image]

How can you adjust the above screen shot so that "Table of Contents" appears as an entry above Summary? That is, I want to include the ToC as part of the ToC.

Comment: Use `\usepackage{tocbibind}` -- your `\section*{Summary}` won't appear in the ToC however (at least not with this code) And please don't use `...` in the document preamble -- it means typesettings dots which is isn't possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tocbibind` package is the easiest way to achieve this. It has multiple options to prevent the `LoF`, `LoT` or `bib` in the ToC, if needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=6mm, bottom=14mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\title{COMPUTATIONAL METHODS FOR THE RIEMANN ZETA FUNCTION}
\author{Axion004}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble} %????
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
%\pagestyle{axionstyle}
\pagenumbering{arabic}%
\section*{Summary}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the `memoir` class (which is a superset of the `book,`report`and`article` classes it is as simple as

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir}
...
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
```

Using `\tableofcontents*` instead gives the same result as `\tableofcontents` does in `book/report` classes