# Add entry "Contents" in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I have maybe the same problem as this closed question : [add table of contents in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27687/add-table-of-contents-in-table-of-contents)

I want the line "Table of contents" to appear in my Table of Contents, with page number and so on.

I tried to put `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of contents}` below the `\tableofcontents` command with no result.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of contents}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{tocbibind}` will add the `Contents` to the ToC itself. Or use the `memoir` class where this is done automatically, unless `\tableofcontents*` is applied

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It works very well, thanks ! But how to adapt the name of the line instead of "Table of contents" ?

Comment: That depends on your setup. Are you using `babel`? No? Then `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}` should be sufficient

Comment: What's the point of adding the table of contents to the table of contents? When you read the toc, you know it's the toc, you don't have to find at which page it is to be found!

Comment: @Bernard: well, the only application in my point of view is to have the ToC in the bookmarks, but the on the other hand, the other ToC entries are most likely in the bookmarks as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
\begin{document}

\listoftoc[Something like the Table of \contentsname]{toc}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

You can replace "`Something like the Table of \contentsname`" by whatever should be the title of the table of contents. You need at least two LaTeX runs after changing the title.